# Navicat add fields to existing table

Tags: mysql, navicat

Using the Navicat application. I have a set of additional data that I want to add to and existing MySQL table. The new data has a column to key with the existing table, plus 35 additional fields of data.

How can Navicat be used to add in these new fields of data via interface? The import tools don't see to add new fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the table you want to modify
2. Click on **File** => **Design Table** to open the table designer
3. Select the position where you want to add the field and click **Insert Field** at the top bar
4. Enter the details of the field such as name, type, length etc.
5. Click Save to effect your changes[image]

[image: Adding a field to mysql table in Navicat]

Answer (score 1):

The data import tool does not support add new fields to existing table. Please add these new fields via Table Design form first, then import your data using data import tool.

If you have any problem, feel free to send a mail to our support team at support@navicat.com.

Answer (score 1):

Run ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name column_characteristics; as described at the following URL in a Navicat query window.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/378/add-a-column-to-an-existing-mysql-table/

Make sure to add ";" at the end of each line.

This will allow you to add multiple columns/fields at once, easier then adding them one-by-one with Navicat's design table tool.

Once columns/fields are in import as usual